# Continue function after change view - Angularjs, Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I have ionic 3 app and function:

```
timerCounter(): void {
  this.counter++;
}
```

when the function is executed it will count 1,2,3,4 but how to keep function process when I change view? (switch to other pages)

Comment: Put the counter in a service, which is a singleton and lives as long as the app does.

Comment: how to do this? I am new in angular/ionic

Comment: @Gocha Refer this article: https://www.joshmorony.com/when-to-use-providersservicesinjectables-in-ionic/